# How do I set a fallback for a GTK+ theme?

Tags: themes, gtk3, gtk-2

I was looking for a way to apply a custom GTK3 theme on a per application basis like can be done with GTK2 but it appears it can't be done as there are open questions here that have not been resolved.

With that being the case, I was searching for a way to set the fallback/default gtk3 theme that the system uses when a GTK2 theme won't work. I am running NOX/Ecstacia GTK2 theme but it fails to theme quite a few apps, (evence,transmission,etc..) as well as some core apps in my xubuntu 12.04 install like software center.

Since NOX is a dark theme, I would like to use a dark GTK3 theme as the fallback like Blapple or Marples.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. I would suggest creating a hybrid theme. This way you won't need to edit files as root, or experience any complications when a theme you have modified is upgraded.

First create a copy of it under `~/.themes`:

> mkdir -p ~/.themes
>
> cp -r /usr/share/themes/NOX ~/.themes/NOX-Custom

Next, copy over the `gtk-3.0` subfolder from an existing theme. For example:

> cp -r /usr/share/themes/selene/gtk-3.0 ~/.themes/NOX-Custom/

Finally, customize name for your new theme in the `index.theme` file found under the theme folder.

> gedit ~/.themes/NOX-Custom/index.theme